# VLC 3.0.12/3.0.14 once command source build fails on macOS

Tags: macos, vlc, libvlc, macos-mojave

Running mac osx 10.14.6 and have previously successfully built 3.0.10 and 3.0.11. Trying to build VLC 3.0.12 & 3.0.14 from source downloaded from here: http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-sources.html

and using recommended build from here: https://wiki.videolan.org/MacOSCompile/ AND using the recommended:

`../extras/package/macosx/build.sh -c`

Build runs for about 20 minutes and then stops here (snip of output):

```
CCLD     libprefetch_plugin.la
CCLD     libhds_plugin.la
CCLD     librecord_plugin.la
ld: library not found for -lzstd
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[4]: *** [libarchive_plugin.la] Error 1
make[4]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
mysystem:build xx$
```

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Note: in previous builds I could find a `cmake/Utilities/cmzstd/lib`  directory in `vlc-3.0.x/extras/tools` that had various `zstd` files however it is not there in either 3.0.12 or 3.0.14 - only a `cmake-enable-ALPN-support-on-macOS-109.14.patch` file.

Where do I find zstd? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Seems the issue is related to how macOS and packagers (homebrew, etc.) load components. macOS provides a compiled version of libarchive but no headers, so you are unable in trying to compile. You will either need to pass the location of your libarchive respository with headers via your build script or set an environment variable telling the compiler or linker where to look for them. Perhaps someone more familiar with your VLC package can weigh in.